# OpenCV, findContours - Why do we need a <vector<vector<Point>> to store the contours? Why not just <vector<Point>>?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I have a variable where the contour points are stored:

```
<vector<vector<Point>> contours;
```

There are points/coordinates stored in:

```
contours[0][0].x; contours[0][0].y;
contours[0][1].x; contours[0][1].y;
...
contours[0][n].x; contours[0][n].y;
```

But no points/coordinates are stored in:

```
contours[1][0].x; contours[1][0].y;
contours[1][1].x; contours[1][1].y;
...
contours[1][n].x; contours[1][n].y;
```

or

```
contours[n][0].x; contours[n][0].y;
contours[n][1].x; contours[n][1].y;
...
contours[n][n].x; contours[n][n].y;
```

So why do we need a vector of vector of points, instead of a vector of points?
A vector of points would be sufficient or not? But openCV wants a vector of vector of points.

Comment: One vector of points would be **a** contour (if you stuffed all the points from multiple countours in one vector how would you tell them apart?). You need a vector of vectors to keep track of **contours**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, why there are no contour points stored in contours[n][k] for all n > 0, you may have only one contour in your contours vector, which is contours[0].

The reason for the vector in a vector is because the

```
vector<Point>
```

nested inside the first vector only stores one contour. OpenCV uses

```
 vector<vector<Point>>
```

to store multiple contours. This is needed when OpenCV does findContours(); as it needs to use multiple contours to represent the connected components.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yes, I have just one contour in my image. I didn't think about multiple contours.